# How to subtract from dictionary with a specific string format

Tags: python

How do i subtract a dictionary `dictionary = {"A": 10, "B": 12, "C": 14}` from the values in a string `string = '1A 3C'` such that the end result is `dictionary = {"A": 9, "B": 12, "C": 11}` ? (3C means substract the value in Key "C" by 3).

The list and dictionary are not going to be static but the letters will always be in alphabetical order

I tried to do something like a loop but I'm not sure where to even begin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier  tested and working example without using regular expressions and additional modules, just builtins, but works only if the dictionary keys are guaranteed to be 1 letter long, while the number to be subtracted can be as long as you want:

```py
string = '1A 3C'
dictio = {"A": 10, "B": 12, "C": 14}
for token in string.split(): # split string at spaces and unpack the resulting substrings
    value, key = token[:-1], token[-1] # value contains all letters of token except the last and key the last
    dictio[key] -= int(value) # convert value to a number and subtract the number from it's corresponding dictionary value

print(dictio)
```

Output:

```py
{'A': 9, 'B': 12, 'C': 11}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

# 1 or more digits followed by at least one non-digit char
pat = re.compile(r"^(\d+)(\D+)$") 

# If there are negative numbers, e.g. "1A -3C"
# pat = re.compile(r"^(\-?\d+)(\D+)$") 


for token in string.split():
    m = pat.match(token)
    if m:
        v = int(m.group(1))  # first capturing group: the numeric value
        k = m.group(2)  # second capturing group: the dict key
        dictionary[k] -= v
```

A non-regex way to extract key and numeric value from a token would be:

```
def fun(token):
    num = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(token):
        if c.isdigit():
            num = num*10 + int(c)
        else:
            return num, token[i:]
    # do what needs doing if token does not have the expected form

# and in the loop
k, v = fun(token)
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this without regular expressions? Seems a bit advanced for me

Comment: @Jon yes there is, see my answer !

Comment: @Jon I am not a friend of regular expressions ;) !

Comment: You could manually iterate through each token until you hit a non-digit. But the code will be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `'1A 3C'` itself to dictionary like `{'C': '3', 'A': '1'}` then you can subtract based on key.

```py
dictionary = {"A": 10, "B": 12, "C": 14}

string = '1A 3C'

dict_string = {i[-1]:i[:-1] for i in string.split(' ')}


for k in dict_string:
    dictionary[k] -= int(dict_string[k])
    
print(dictionary)
```

```
{'A': 9, 'B': 12, 'C': 11}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
dictionary["C"] -= 3
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It doesn't use `string` at all.